# Heat Equation on Disk with Heat Source

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given the heat equation with a source term in polar coordinates.

$$
u_{t} = k ( \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r  \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) + \frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}) + g(r,\theta,t)
$$

The boundary conditions are such that:
$$
u(1,\theta, t)= 0, u(r,0, t)= u(r,\frac{\pi}{2}, t)=0
$$

The initial condition is some function such that $ u(r,\theta, 0) = f(r,\theta,t)$.

I've attempted solving for the solution through eigenfunction expansion, but I may need a different method to solve the above PDE.

Is there a better way to go about this than through eigenfunction expansion?

Comment: I would conformally map the slit disk onto a more convenient region.